# Angular - Federation Module - WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost.xxx.com:4200/ng-cli-ws' failed:

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-module-federation

Working Module federation with Angular, i update the angular.json file and update the `publicHost` to `host` as following

```
"options": {
   "port": 4200,
   "host": "localhost.xxx.com:4200",
   "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js"
 },
```

When running the project i am getting the following error in the browser console

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost.xxx.com:4200/ng-cli-ws' failed:
```

if i change the `host` back to `publicHost` with value of `http://localhost:4200` error goes away in console.
Any suggestions?

I am thinking if i need to make a change in the webpack config to fix the websocket issue.